# Regular expression to allow alphanumeric and special chars with space, but not only numerics with space

Tags: regex

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z\s?():,/][a-zA-Z0-9\s?():,/]*$
```

Above is the expression I am using to:

- block numbers only
- allow alphabets with special chars and space
- allow alphanumeric with special chars and space

Now I need to block numbers entered with space as well. please assist.

Comment: Could you just give us some examples of bad entries vs good entries?

Comment: Test123 - Good
Test 123 ? - Good 3432432

Comment: Test123: Good,
Test 123 ?:  Good, 3432432: - bad, 3432432 : bad, 1221321?(): good

Answer (score 0):

`[^0-9 ]*`: notice that there IS a space inside the brackets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You're right on track.

The expression for the general use case would be

```
^[optional]*[required][allowed]*$
```

In `optional`, put all characters that could be in the string but are not required. In `required`, leave only those that should appear at least once. `allowed` should contain the union of both.

For your case, the optional characters are all digits and space:

```
^[0-9\s]*[A-Za-z()?:,/][A-Za-z0-9\s()?:,/]*$
```

Comment: Notice that `\s` matches more than just a space (also CR LF tab \v and \f). If you want to exclude them simply use a space.